# React-Router-4 example (w Redux + SSR) help needed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am trying to figure it out own to integrate all of this (redux, rr4, SSR, ...)
I decided to start with a boilerplate that I liked and that is very easy to experiment with.

In the following PR I am upgrading this project to RR4+SSR:
https://github.com/CrocoDillon/universal-react-redux-boilerplate/pull/25

I have some trouble that I describe in the PR. Basically: ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup trigger the componentWillMount on SSR which mess up with the state on the client (see the PR).

Any contribution to my repo is warmly welcomed:
https://github.com/rolele/universal-react-redux-boilerplate

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks